# technology used on a website

Tags: javascript, material-design

I have come up to a website: https://resourcetrade.earth/data?year=2016&importer=12&units=value and would like to know what technology is being used.

I have done some research and it looks like material design.

Does anyone know how to find out more.

JS libraries are compressed so it is hard to read through the code.

Comment: Use [BuiltWith](http://builtwith.com) or something like it.

Comment: Looks like dynamically generated svgs. Doesn't look like anything standard is being used (e.g. google maps, three.js). Note that this question will almost certainly be closed, it's not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: svg looks like is for the map https://resourcetrade.earth/embed?year=2016&importer=12&units=value  but dropdown components are the ones that are intriguing.

Comment: @mpora it's just a custom drop down in HTML/CSS. It's not from a library as far as I can tell